# react-native-sound-player not showing controls in UI

Tags: react-native, audio-streaming, react-native-ios

I have integrated following library to my react native project to play audio from URL.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player

It is working fine, But, No media control is showing (play/pause/progressbar)

It is just playing audio.

```js
import SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player'


    try {
        // or play from url
        SoundPlayer.playUrl('https://example.com/music.mp3')
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e)
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs it doesn't seem like there is a UI component in that library.

You probably have to render the buttons yourself and attach an onPress function on them.

Like:

```
<Button 
    onPress={()=>SoundPlayer.playUrl('https://example.com/music.mp3')} 
    title={"Play"}
/>
```

Comment: But, I have to show Progressbar(Slider), Play/Pause/Stop, Title. And I have to play audio in background state too. I am new to react-native

Comment: As said, you have to create the components yourself and using the functions this library gives you, create a UI that shows a player. Slider, play, pause and everything else doesn't come out of the box using this single library, but it's possible to create them and style them however you want

Comment: Any example for that UI?

Comment: Try to follow this article to create the UI: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-music-streaming-app-using-react-native-6d0878a13ba4, using the functions you have inside react-native-sound-player you should be able to create it

Comment: Edited, try it now

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue at end?

Comment: No, Reca-Native-Video library not supporting older versions of android sdk. So, I have customised controls according to my UI and play the audio. Thats it.